# Nano Pi R2S Status LEDS Configuration

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04, nanopi

I have a Nano Pi R2S on Ubuntu 20.04 and I am trying to configure the WAN and LAN led of the unit. Please excuse my low skill set. According to the guide (https://wiki.friendlyelec.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_R2S#Config_status_LEDs) I need to put the following into a auto run script.

```
echo netdev > /sys/class/leds/wan_led/trigger
echo eth0 > /sys/class/leds/wan_led/device_name
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/wan_led/link
 
echo netdev > /sys/class/leds/lan_led/trigger
echo eth1 > /sys/class/leds/lan_led/device_name
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/lan_led/link
```

Here is my ledstatus.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo netdev > /sys/class/leds/wan_led/trigger
echo eth0 > /sys/class/leds/wan_led/device_name
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/wan_led/link

echo netdev > /sys/class/leds/lan_led/trigger
echo eth1 > /sys/class/leds/lan_led/device_name
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/lan_led/link
```

This is my errors.

```
./statusled.sh: line 3: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./statusled.sh: line 4: /sys/class/leds/wan_led/device_name: Permission denied
./statusled.sh: line 5: /sys/class/leds/wan_led/link: Permission denied
./statusled.sh: line 7: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./statusled.sh: line 8: /sys/class/leds/lan_led/device_name: Permission denied
./statusled.sh: line 9: /sys/class/leds/lan_led/link: Permission denied
```

Comment: Are you doing this as root/sudo ? The error message is self-explanatory.

Comment: Yes I have tried sudo.

Comment: It also says invalid argument.

Comment: Just to clarify, do the individual commands work? Is this just the statusled.sh script that is problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue but fixed, invalid argument here is not invalid for `echo`, but for the file `/sys/class/leds/wan_led/trigger`.
The `trigger` needs a specific value, you can run `cat /sys/class/leds/wan_led/trigger` to see all valid value, as for the output of `cat`: the [value] is selected, and the others are options,you must echo one of them, or you got "invalid "